# function behaves differently when using global variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables, console

```
let outsideVariable = 5;

  function myFunctionTests(){
    let checkBox = document.getElementById("checkTests");
    let variableName = 10;
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        variableName += 1;
        outsideVariable += 1;
        console.log('variableName is: ',variableName);
        console.log('outsideVariable is: ',outsideVariable);
    } else {
        variableName -= 1;
        outsideVariable -= 1;
        console.log('variableName is: ',variableName);
        console.log('outsideVariable is: ',outsideVariable);
    }
  }
```

When I run this code and I tick the checkbox, both variables ("variableName" and "outsideVariable") go up by 1 (output is 11 and 6). So far so good.

Now when I untick the checkbox, "variableName" goes down by 1 (based on the initial value of 10, so it goes to 9 as expected), but "outsideVariable" goes back to 5, instead of going to 4.

The only way to make "outsideVariable" go to 4 is to change

outsideVariable -= 1;

to

outsideVariable -= 2;

Any special reason why this happens?
I'm learning JavaScript, so take that into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

you want when checkbox uncheck, variableName = 10 and outsideVariable = 5, but they are equals to 9 and 4, right? for that problem you shoud define variableName in out of scope like global scope!.

Comment: No, that's the problem. As you can see on my code, I want the ticked box to add 1 to both variables and the unticked box to subtract 1 from both variables. So:
Ticked would output 11 and 6 (adds 1). Unticked would output: 9 and 4 (subtracts 1). Right now what's happening is: Ticked outputs 11 and 6 (works as expected. No issues here). Unticked outputs 9 and 5 (the 9 is good for "variableName"), but why is the global "outsideVariable" variable going to 5 instead of 4?

Comment: @Tiago its ok for me! when i check checkbox, variableName is 11 and outsideVariable is 5 and when i uncheck that, the output was 9 and 4!. Where do you use this function? i use this function with click event listener and output was ok!

Comment: I was just using the console. No functions or anything. I just change another variable's name that affects those variables

Comment: @Tiago you need first learn how programming language work!. next learn about javascript. Your function, once run at the beginning of the program, should be used when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: why wouldn't I learn everything at the same time? We all make mistakes any way, whether we are beginners or experts. ;) I'm learning while I'm testing things. Nothing wrong about that, in my opinion. But I now know the code runs once when the page loads so I need to test it differently. Thanks!

Comment: @DannyWyatt Use the arrow up to rate my comments and answers. thanks :)